# Terminating a thread immediately and safely (C#)

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I'm in the process of writing a simple "Score Attack" Poker game. A player assembles poker hands which are worth points as a timer ticks down. My problem is a game over scenario.

My game logic runs in a single thread since the game itself is so simple. I need to know how to terminate that thread as it is, with the player no longer able to make input. I've read on the MSDN that the safe way to do this is to use a loop to cause the thread's method to return and end the thread. The problem I run into is that my game requires user input, and the user input would cause the loop to not be checked at the moment the timer ticks to zero.

The code so far uses the Thread.Abort(), and it works, but from my searching on this site that is universally regarded as a bad idea. Is there any way I could set a condition that would terminate the thread safely regardless of methods within said thread needing input? (Console.ReadLine())

Code for the game loop and timer callback that aborts the thread:

```
private void GameLoop()
{
    double stash = 0;
    while (true)
    {
    player.SwapCards(gameDeck);
    Table.WriteInfo("Stash This Hand? y/n");              
    if (Console.ReadLine().Equals("y"))
        {
          countdown += (int)ScoreHand(player.Hand);
          stash += ScoreHand(player.Hand); 
          BankHand();
        }             
    }
}


private void TimeDrop(object state)
    {
        countdown--;
        Debug.WriteLine(countdown);
        if (countdown == 0)
        {              
            GameThread.Abort();
            GameOverThread.Start();
            Timer.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

As it sits the loop simply runs until the thread is aborted.

Edit:

Upon request, the code the starts the threads:

```
 public Game()
    {                    
        gameDeck = new Deck();
        InitPlayer();            
        DealHand();

        countdown = 60;
        GameThread = new Thread(GameLoop);
        GameOverThread = new Thread(GameOver);

        Timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(TimeDrop), null, 0, 1000);
        Timer.Change(0, 1000); //Ensures timer won't be garbage collected
        GameThread.Start();
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code that creates the game thread?

Comment: Aborting a thread is almost always a bad idea. You can ask the `Console` if there's a key available looking with a short sleep, rather than blocking on a `ReadLine` call.

Comment: @Flydog57 I'm not sure what you mean. Could you point me to the function or technique you are referring to?

Comment: What you need to do is message the other thread and have it terminate itself naturally. Any call to `Thread.Abort()` should only be made if you are trying to crash out of your app. In all other cases, do not call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of thing can be implemented easier and cleaner using async/await rather than threads.

First we need to wrap the blocking console input method with one that is cancellable (and async). The method polls the console using `KeyAvailable` and asynchronously delaying while checking the `CancellationToken`.

```
    public static async Task<ConsoleKeyInfo> ReadKeyAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            await Task.Delay(100, cancellationToken);
        }
        return Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Now we can start this async method and pass a cancellation token from a `CancellationTokenSource` that will automatically cancel after a specific amount of time (10 seconds as an example).

```
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have 10 seconds to press the Y key...");
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(10_000);
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var key = await ReadKeyAsync(cts.Token);
                if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Y)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Good job!");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Wrong Key");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.Write("Time up!");
        }
    }
```